# Disable gpu accelerated rendering

Tags: html, browser, web

The are some rendering issues with my website under some browsers (eg Chrome on Windows & Mac, Safari on Mac) related to gpu acceleration and I was wondering if there is a way to disable it for my website. Something like a `<meta>` tag I could include in my pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is not.

You should explain what the rendering issues are, and see if we can help you work around them.